# Setting correct value to JSF element

Tags: java, jsf, servlets, javabeans

I'm trying to acces an JSF Element from a Java Bean, so I can use it in my app, but I need to send the text from a `textarea` to a `<f:setPropertyActionListener />` The problem is that I don't know how to tell the `<f:setPropertyActionListener />` to take the `textarea value

I'm sure that is a little grammar mistake, but I can't see it U__U

Here's a pice of code, I would be very gratefull if you tell me how to do it in future cases, cause I'm gonna need it ;)

```
<h:form>
        <h:dataTable var="answer" value="#{AnswerController.answer}">
            <h:column>
                #{msgs.newAnswer}<br/>
                <h:inputTextarea id="textanswer" name="text" rows="5" cols="20" /> <br/>
                <h:commandButton value="#{msgs.aceptButton}" type="submit" action="#{AnswerController.newAnswer(answer)}" immediate="true">
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{AnswerController.currentAnswer}"
                        value="textanswer" />
                </h:commandButton>
            </h:column>
        </h:dataTable>              
    </h:form>
```

Comment: Thank's for the tip ;) I'm changing it right now ;)

Comment: `<f:setPropertyActionListener/>` is unnecessary; Just bind the `value` of the `<h:inputTextarea/>` to `#{AnswerController.currentAnswer}`, so you'll have `<h:inputTextarea value="#{AnswerController.currentAnswer}"/>` . Is there anything constraining you from doing that?

Comment: and ifI do that, when i change the value of the inputTextArea it would modify the value in the Bean?

Comment: @kolossus In that case it is necessary to split big forms into many small ones, otherwise OP will end up with final input text's value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the usage of `<f:setPropertyActionListener>` kolossus is right: in case you use EL 2.2, capable of calling methods with parameters, it is not necessary. Otherwise that tag could be used to identify *which* of the command buttons was pressed and ultimately *which* answer should turn up in the bean to be manipulated.

In your case I can see two use cases, both of which are described below.

**Submit exactly one answer**

In this case you should use one form per data iteration so that only one answer will come to the server. Putting kolossus' comment into code, well have:

```
<h:dataTable var="answer" value="#{bean.answers}">
    <h:column>
        <h:form>
            #{msgs.newAnswer}<br/>
            <h:inputTextarea id="textanswer" value="#{bean.currentAnswer}" rows="5" cols="20" /> <br/>
            <h:commandButton value="#{msgs.aceptButton}" action="#{bean.newAnswer}" />
        </h:form>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

With this code, one string property of the bean is enough, and it will be available in a listener method:

```
private String currentAnswer;//getter+setter
```

**Submit all answers**

In this case you should have one form per the datatable, and all answers will end up in a list in backing bean:

```
<h:form>
    <h:dataTable var="answer" value="#{bean.answers}">
        <h:column>
            #{msgs.newAnswer}<br/>
            <h:inputTextarea id="textanswer" value="#{answer}" rows="5" cols="20" /> <br/>
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
    <h:commandButton value="#{msgs.aceptButton}" action="#{bean.newAnswers}" />
</h:form>
```

In this case a list of strings will be populated during form submit and all answers will be available in action method:

```
List<String> answers;//getter+setter
```

---

**Use case of method call with parameter or `<f:setPropertyActionListener>`**

As you see, none of them were used in two setups described above. They are useful if you want to know which answer was selected, so that the right one would be manipulated. Like in:

```
<h:dataTable var="answer" value="#{bean.answers}">
    <h:column>
        <h:form>
            #{msgs.deleteAnswer}<br/>
            <h:inputTextarea id="textanswer" value="#{answer}" rows="5" cols="20" /> <br/>
            <h:commandButton value="#{msgs.deleteButton}" action="#{bean.deleteAnswer(answer)}" />
        </h:form>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

or alternatively in

```
<h:dataTable var="answer" value="#{bean.answers}">
    <h:column>
        <h:form>
            #{msgs.deleteAnswer}<br/>
            <h:inputTextarea id="textanswer" value="#{answer}" rows="5" cols="20" /> <br/>
            <h:commandButton value="#{msgs.deleteButton}" action="#{bean.deleteAnswer(answer)}">
                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{answer}" target="#{bean.currentAnswer}" />
            </h:commandButton>
        </h:form>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

In the first example answer associated with the button click will be available as method parameter, and in the second example answer associated with button click will be set to bean property before action method is called and will be available as `currentAnswer` bean property.